# Google Cloud API

Tags: google-api, google-api-client, google-cloud-datastore

I would like to know if is there any way to list all available projects in a user cloud account?.

I want to select one project from all available and the run all other APIs based on selected project. Now I have to write manually the project name.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I have found, it's not possible.

Found in https://developers.google.com/compute/docs/projects

> **Note:** There is no Google Compute Engine command to list projects; you
>   must use the Developers Console to list projects of which you are a
>   member.

Comment: This refers to the `gcloud` command. There could still be a REST API, although (unfortunately) it may not exist either.